# jqGrid noticeably slower in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jqgrid

We've noticed that the jqGrid sort/pagination performance is noticeably slower in IE vs FFox and Chrome.  Is this just 'how it is' or are there any perf improvements that can be applied?

Comment: Which version of IE? IE6 was known to be a bad behaving browser but the new IE9 beta's super fast for me. IE8 was also pretty ok.

Comment: IE8 actually.  The test I'm running is with 11K records.  The sorting and pagination is much slower than FFox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the main problem why jqGrid could be slower in IE is that JavaScript in IE is slower as in other browsers. So jQuery and jqGrid must work solwer. See http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-performance-rundown/ for example. You can find much more more ricent tests about the same subject.